problema grande de indexación en google search console
tengo 207 paginas sin indexar, supongo que por varias razones pero temo que ha influido el que he cambiado 3 veces de hosting el los ultimos años.
Adjunto el estado en GSC: 
Así que he pensado empezar por las "No se ha encontrado (404)" que son 62 pero no entiendo cual es el problema y como lo puedo corregir.
Despues he pensado seguir con "Rastreada: actualmente sin indexar" que son 103 pero no se como eliminar esas pagina que no existen en mi dashboard/escritorio, ni en paginas ni en entradas, y que terminan en /feed/.
Tengo la web desde 2014 y al empezar no tenía ni idea y supongo que cometí muchos errores...
Asi que he borrado todos los tags, todas las categorias y he dejado solo 12 páginas y 81 entradas /posts, hace un total de 93 , ¿de donde sale una ingente cantidad de 207 paginas sin indexar? puede ser por los tags de imágenes? si es así me puedo morir porque en elementos de medios tengo 1680 elementos. ¿Como puedo borrar todo esto en bloque?
Me han aconsejado de eliminarlo de GSC pero veo que es un apaño temporal.
Yo solo quiero saber como eliminar esas paginas raras que no entiendo y que no encuentro en ningún sitio como:
COmo esta que acaba en feed/ : https://flytodigital.com/soluciones-google-para-empresas/feed/
o esta: https://flytodigital.com/posiciona-tu-tienda-online-accion-4-ten-un-blog/<br
no soy desarrolladora web , si alguien fuese tan amable de explicarme que significa y como lo puedo solucionar sin morir en el intento. Gracias de antemano.
He exportado dos exceles uno con el de 62 paginas tipo "deprecated" (os añado una imagen) y otro de 103 paginas tipo  /feed/  
Se me olvidó que he vuelto a enviar el site map y ahora ha disminuido las indexadas, eso es bueno? os añado un 3er pantallazo 
He pensado cortar por lo sano y borrar las 81 entradas pero hay trabajo de muchos años...la verdad no sé que hacer. Ya os podeis imagina como esta mi SEO , debajo de los suelos

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

creo que está bastante claro lo que necesito. Necesito entender porque esas páginas han sido indexadas y saber como solucionar este problema
